# How can i run querySelectorAll if my third-party software does not allow/read <!DOCTYPE> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, doctype

I am developing a web page that needs to be integrated to my third-party software and outputs to HTML web page. But my software does not allow nor read **DOCTYPEs**. How can I rework this code without using DOCTYPEs.

```
note that my problem is not with the codes, but how to remake the codes for them to
work without the DOCTYPE tag
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Here is the simple code.

**BROWSER: INTERNET EXPLORER 8**

**JS:**

```
function myFunctionClass(){

var mo = document.querySelectorAll(".displayBlockClass");
var getYr = document.getElementById("date1Year");
var m;
for (m = 0; m < mo.length; m++){

if(getYr.value == "2001" || getYr.value == "2003" || getYr.value == "2005"){
   mo[m].style.display = "";
}
else{
   mo[m].style.display = "none";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You don't need to 'read the doctype' test if the browser supports it. You will need a polyfill just in case the browser does not support this feature. Have a look at: https://gist.github.com/connrs/2724353

Comment: Thanks jeff, how can I rework my current js with the codes you've given me? I'm sorry I am new to Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

If an old version of IE lacks support to `document.querySelectorAll` in [quirks mode](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html) and you cannot have a `DOCTYPE` at the start of a document, you need to use some polyfill. There seems to be a simple polyfill [qsa-polyfill-ie7.js](https://gist.github.com/connrs/2724353) that does the job:

```
if (!document.querySelectorAll) {
  document.querySelectorAll = function(selector) {
  var doc = document,
      head = doc.documentElement.firstChild,
      styleTag = doc.createElement('STYLE');
   head.appendChild(styleTag);
   doc.__qsaels = [];
   styleTag.styleSheet.cssText = selector + 
      "{x:expression(document.__qsaels.push(this))}";
   window.scrollBy(0, 0);
   return doc.__qsaels;
   }
}
```

Make this executed before first call to `document.querySelectorAll`